# THREEJS Convert XYZ coordinate to Object rotation

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, rotation, geometry

I'm working with THREE JS. I have a sphere object (made using THREE.SphereGeometry) and inside this sphere I have another smaller sphere. Both spheres have the same center (so the smaller sphere sits exactly in the middle of the bigger sphere). My camera is located inside the bigger sphere and I can see the inside surface of the bigger sphere (Im inside a 3D shop). Here I create the bigger outer sphere:

```
setupSphereProjection() {
    // creation of a big sphere geometry
    //THREE.SphereGeometry(SPHERE RADIUS, WIDTH SEGMENTS, HEIGHT SEGMENTS)
    this.sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(sphereRadius, 40, 40);
    this.sphere.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(-1, 1, 1));

    // creation of the sphere material
    let sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

    let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    sphereMaterial.map = loader.load(testImage);

    // geometry + material = mesh (actual object)
    this.sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.sphere, sphereMaterial);
    this.scene.add(this.sphereMesh);
}
```

My setup is such that when I click on the surface of the bigger sphere I get an XYZ coordinate of the click on the bigger sphere surface. What I want is for the smaller sphere to rotate to face the location of the XYZ coordinate. (so when the user clicks on the surface of the bigger sphere the smaller sphere rotates to look at the location of the click on the outer sphere). Here is the THREE.Vector3 I get when I click on the surface of the outer sphere (radius is 100):

```
THREEE.Vector3 {x: -8.755543860298761, y: -2.284054920077946, z: -99.22118491615181}
```

I'm struggling to convert the XYZ coordinate into a rotation of the inner sphere. I'm not sure if I should use Quaternions or Euler angles or both. I've tried different approaches and none of them have worked so far. Any help/advice would be warmly welcomed.

Comment: Try `smallerSphere.lookAt( vector )`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "I want for the smaller sphere to rotate to face the location of the XYZ coordinate"?

Comment: @WestLangley thanks for the advice I will try the .lookAt() method and let you know if it works.

Comment: @gaitat I mean: I want the smaller inner sphere to rotate from its current position to the direction of the XYZ coordinate that i clicked at on the outer sphere. Im guessing, but im not sure what the default in three js is, that the x-axis of the smaller sphere will then move from its current position to face in the direction of the xyz coord.

Comment: @user3767327 The sphere's positive-z axis will be oriented toward the lookAt() target.